# Nested ng-repeat on dynamic data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two arrays of objects. One contains all distinct items with respective item details - the other array contains owners of these items. For example owners[itemid].ownerName would be the name of one of the owners of the item with id 'itemid'. Both of these arrays are updated every few seconds. In particular a new owner is added.

I have an ng-repeat which displays each item (with its details) and then a nested ng-repeat which I would want to use to display each owner. The way my code is written is summarised below:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    Example: {{item.name}}
    <div ng-repeat="owner in owners[item.id]">
        Owner ID: {{owner.id}}
    </div>
</div>
```

As it is now the nested ng-repeat shows the correct **number** of owners but the owners are all identical (i.e. the first owner). Perhaps someone could shed light on a solution (i.e. how to get each owner to display its actual id)? I'm new to Angular! Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide code example or a fiddle? I've made a quick JSBin and it works fine: http://jsbin.com/recadigu/1/ .

Comment: The problem (I think) is that owners is being updated (an owner is added) via $http every few seconds. So, at first there is only one owner associated to every item that is being displayed. Then, the owner.id 'sticks' for every subsequent owner added.

Comment: you should add the code that modifies your data

Comment: This little bit of syntax helped me get my nested ng-repeat working.  Thanks!  owners[item.id]